# Retrieving child objects from parent node

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I've followed what I think to be the most up-to-date recommendations for Firebase to structure a flattened database like so:

[image]

Categories and SubCategories are separate nodes with Categories having a reference to the keys of SubCategories which are its children.

I then wanted to be able to run a query based on a Categories key and return its child SubCategories.

I based my code on this (outdated) example, which is the only example I could find - from https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html

```
var commentsRef = new Firebase("https://awesome.firebaseio-demo.com/comments");
var linkRef = new Firebase("https://awesome.firebaseio-demo.com/links");
var linkCommentsRef = linkRef.child(LINK_ID).child("comments");
linkCommentsRef.on("child_added", function(snap) {
  commentsRef.child(snap.key()).once("value", function() {
    // Render the comment on the link page.
  ));
});
```

And tried to convert it to run on Android with a best-guess replacement for the methods which no longer exist from the example above:

```
final DatabaseReference subCategoriesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(user.getUid()).child("SubCategories");
    DatabaseReference categoriesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(user.getUid()).child("Categories");
    Query categoriesSubCategoriesRef = categoriesRef.child(EXTRA_CATEGORY_KEY).child("SubCategories");
    categoriesSubCategoriesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            subCategoriesRef.child(dataSnapshot.getKey());
            subCategoriesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    //Log.v("item", dataSnapshot.child("SubCategories").child("SubCategoryName").getValue().toString());
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

It *kind of* works, but it returns **all** of the SubCategories, not just the ones which are children of the Category I specified with the EXTRA_CATEGORY_KEY, which it then returns as a Json object:

```
DataSnapshot { key = SubCategories, value = {-KZ8aQOhk1r7tj5gjM97={
Description=, isChecked=false, ID=103, Published=1, SubCategoryName=Name1, hasExtra=false, Deleted=0, CategoryID=8}, 
-KZ8aQP98TujvnjAERXF={Description=, isChecked=false, ID=40, Published=1, SubCategoryName=Name2, hasExtra=false, Deleted=0, CategoryID=2},...
```

...And so on.

Firstly: is my data structure correct, or have I followed a deprecated recommendation? And secondly: what's the problem with my query?

**EDIT:** This is the current (incorrect) full structure of the database. Each user is private, they cannot share any of their data with any other user.

```
{
  "users": {
    "Uc6PJMfq5VZpT2V7EHMmmGPk0Zv2": {
  "Categories": {
    "-KZ8aQPi5QXrFv_RrKIh": {
      "CategoryName": "",
      "Constant": "",
      "Deleted": 0,
      "Description": "",
      "ID": 1,
      "Published": 1,
      "Sequence": 1,
      "SubCategories": {
        "-KZ8aQPHbCTtveAfR_D8": true,
        "-KZ8aQPHbCTtveAfR_D9": true
      }
    }
  },
  "SubCategories": {
    "-KZ8aQPHbCTtveAfR_D8": {
      "CategoryID": 1,
      "Deleted": 0,
      "Description": "",
      "ID": 1,
      "Published": 1,
      "SubCategoryName": "",
      "hasExtra": false,
      "isChecked": false
    },
    "-KZ8aQPHbCTtveAfR_D9": {
      "CategoryID": 1,
      "Deleted": 0,
      "Description": "",
      "ID": 21,
      "Published": 1,
      "SubCategoryName": "",
      "hasExtra": false,
      "isChecked": false
    }
  },
  "journal": {
    "-KYzQOrMrEenlXobzG3d": {
      "entry": "Test entry",
      "entryDate": {
        "date": 14,
        "day": 3,
        "hours": 22,
        "minutes": 22,
        "month": 11,
        "seconds": 5,
        "time": 1481754125034,
        "timezoneOffset": 0,
        "year": 116
      },
      "id": "",
      "source": "journal"
    }
  },
  "userDetails": {
    "email": "",
    "username": ""
  }
},
"anotheruniqueuser": {
  "Categories": {
  },
  "SubCategories": {        
  },
  "journal": {
  },
  "userDetails": {
    "email": "",
    "username": ""
  }
}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample snippet you copied listens to a `child_added` event, which translates to `ChildEventListener.onChildAdded` in Java.

The snippet becomes:

```
DatabaseReference categoriesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Categories");
DatabaseReference subCategoriesRef = categoriesRef.child(user.getUid()).child("SubCategories");
DatabaseReference categoriesRef = categoriesRef.child(user.getUid()).child("Categories");
DatabaseReference categoriesSubCategoriesRef = categoriesRef.child(EXTRA_CATEGORY_KEY).child("SubCategories");

categoriesSubCategoriesRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {    
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot keySnapshot, String previousChildKey) {
        subCategoriesRef.child(keySnapshot.getKey());
        subCategoriesRef.addSingleValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.v("item", dataSnapshot.child("SubCategories").child("SubCategoryName").getValue().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    });

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw dataError.toException();
    }
});
```

A few comments:

- The only method in the snippet that doesn't exist anymore is `new Firebase("https://awesome.firebaseio-demo.com/links")`, which translates to `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("links")`.
- You seem to be mixing users and categories at will in your code. At best it's confusing, but more likely it's wrong. I did my best to make sense of the mix in the code above, but likely failed.
- You have multiple types of data under each user. To follow the best practices from the Firebase documentation, separate the metadata of a category (stuff like its name, description, numeric ID, etc) from the building of a hierarchy of them.

  ```
  Categories
      category1
          name: ...
          description: ...
      category2
          name: ...
          description: ...
      category3
          name: ...
          description: ...
  Parents
      category2: category1
      category3: category1
  Children
      category1
          category2: true
          category3: true
  ```

Comment: Thanks Frank, obviously I'll need to refactor my database before trying out your suggestion, but it looks good. I'm not sure what you mean about mixing users and categories at will, but maybe that's because I didn't include my full database structure, which I have done now (even though it is incorrect).